# Opening an iframe for IE while using Chrome Frame

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, google-chrome-frame

I'm trying to use Chrome Frame for a business web application and so far things are working well. However, I need to open an iframe that should be rendered using IE's engine and not Chrome Frame's renderer. The iframe doesn't have the `meta` tag for Chrome Frame yet it renders with the plugin.

Is there a way to open an iframe that is rendered by IE from an app that is rendered by Chrome Frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like it's not supported yet.

> At this point ChromeFrame only supports the meta
>   tag detection on top level URLs.

Source: http://groups.google.com/group/google-chrome-frame/msg/e6d7a4c1c179c931

Comment: Would it be possible to render [IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) inside of Google Chrome Frame?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement for one of the business application that I worked on. After quite few researches, I found that specifying rel="noreferrer" on an  tag will solve the problem. Because as per the documentation for noreferrer on w3schools.com

> Specifies that the browser should not send a HTTP referer header if
>   the user follows the hyperlink

The business application that I'm working on is a single page application, so I placed an  tag on the parent page with attribute rel="noreferrer", like this

```
<a id="linkNoReferrer" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank">&nbsp;</a>
```

I haven't set the 'href' attribute for this  tag, since I would like to assign dynamic href to this  tag and trigger the click manually, like this

```
document.getElementById("linkNoReferrer").href="http://www.google.com";
document.getElementById("linkNoReferrer").click();

or

$("#linkNoReferrer").attr("href","http://www.google.com");
$("#linkNoReferrer").click();
```

You will notice that the new page opened using this method, is rendered not on chrome frame. I have this code running successfully on my business application.

I hope someone would find this useful.

thanks.